# API для видео хостинга

Tags: json, api

Имеется видео база. Теперь предстоит сделать API для парсинга видео.
Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать API, чтобы пользователи смогли парсить контент с помощью API.
Нашел пример того, как должно быть, но не понимаю саму структуру API, откуда, куда и как.
Вот пример (hdgo.cc/api/) (http://hdgo.cc/api/movies.json?token=xx3y2e0c649s501m168rjlos)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [API для видео базы, есть какие мануалы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/717099/api-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%be-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b-%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8b)

Comment: Закодируй в JSON необходимые тебе поля.

Comment: @Erm
`[{
    "title": "Новая Фабрика Звезд",
    "year": "2017",
    "kinopoisk_id": null,
    "world_art_id": null,
    "type": "serial",
    "quality": "среднее DVDRip",
    "seasons_count": 1,
    "episodes_count": 2,
    "iframe_url": "http://hdgo.cc/video/serials/xx3y2e0c649s501m168rjlos/12316/",
    "translator": "Оригинал",
    "id_hdgo": 12316,
    "added_at": "2017-09-11 15:05:29"
}`

Comment: Так а в чем проблема? Есть замечательная функция json_encode

Comment: @Erm Я не могу понять, как реализовать такое на другом видехотинге

Comment: Ну допустим пользователь запрашивает какой-то фильм, а вы берете фиксированные параметры(название/рейтинг/ссылка/жанр) и помещаете в JSON ответ пользователю.

Comment: Так чтобы реализовать API, нужно просто указать данные файлы в данных полях (которые узнать на видеохостинге)? 
А как же по мере поступления видео файл JSON будет дополнятся автоматически?